# Setting the classpath

Tags: shell, classpath

hi i have written one shell script which is performing 1 task.

```
java -jar abc.jar $* -adminid $j_username
```

before this command i want to set classpath(or want to refer) of all jars which are in particular lib folder, how to do that?

Comment: Nit pick: use `"$@"` in place of `$*`.  There are very few places where you want to split the arguments typed by a user at the spaces, and it is unlikely that this is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
set CLASSPATH=pathtojars1;pathtojars2
```

before your java command.

Or:

```
java -classpath
```

Comment: Which shell?  Assuming you use a Bourne Shell derivative (not a C Shell derivative), the `set` command shown tramples the command line arguments; in C Shell derivatives, it sets but does not export the CLASSPATH variable.  In Bourne Shell derivatives, you can write: `CLASSPATH=path1:path2 java ...`.  In C Shell derivatives, use `setenv CLASSPATH path1:path2` followed separately by the `java` command.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be:

```
set CP=abc.jar:someother.jar
java -cp $CP your.main.Class $* -adminid $j_username
```

It is worth while to note that when using `-jar` you can't specify other JARs/resources on the classpath i.e. `-cp` switch is ignored hence you would have to choose between the two.

- Create a standalone JAR which
  incorporates other JARs/resources
- Have different JAR files but instead
  of using `-jar` specify the main
  class when running the program

Comment: The `set` notation only works if using a C shell derivative; if using a Bourne shell derivative, the command clobbers the command line arguments, and `$*` becomes equivalent to `$CP`, which is not what you want.