# Java: DOM how to rename Node Names from a name list

Tags: java, dom, arraylist, rename

I am new to DOM and I have the following requirement.
I have the following simplified XML structure:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ExportData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<DataSet>
    <Tables>
        <Table>
            <Rows>
                <R>
                    <C>101</C>
                    <C>1503</C>
                    <C>2012-02-09 00:00:00</C>
                </R>
                <R>
                    <C>101</C>
                    <C>1503</C>
                    <C>2012-02-09 00:00:00</C>
                </R>
            </Rows>
        </Table>
    </Tables>
</DataSet>
</ExportData>
```

All `<C>` elements (children of `<R>`) I need to rename according to a list of 3 strings.
So the output should look like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ExportData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<DataSet>
    <Tables>
        <Table>
            <Rows>
                <R>
                    <Name1>101</Name1>
                    <Name2>1503</Name2>
                    <Name3>2012-02-09 00:00:00</Name3>
                </R>
                <R>
                    <Name1>101</Name1>
                    <Name2>1503</Name2>
                    <Name3>2012-02-09 00:00:00</Name3>
                </R>
            </Rows>
        </Table>
    </Tables>
</DataSet>
```

I thought DOM would be the best choice to do that. And I came up with the following:

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.*;
import renameElementNames.DOMUtils;

public class ParseNavigate {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    final DOMImplementation domImpl = DOMUtils.getImplementationFromRegistry(DOMUtils.DOM_FEATURE_Core_30_LS);
    final Document doc = DOMUtils.parse(domImpl, new FileInputStream("examplefiles/1503_roh_2012-02-09small.xml"));
    changeTagNames(doc);
    writeXmlFile(doc,"output.xml");
}


public static void changeTagNames (Document doc){
    ArrayList<String> attlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    String name1 = "Name1";String name2 = "Name2";String name3 = "Name3";
    attlist.add(name1);attlist.add(name2);attlist.add(name3);
    
    Node rows = doc.getElementsByTagName("Rows").item(0);
    NodeList rs = rows.getChildNodes();
    
    
    for(int i=0;i<rs.getLength();i++){
        Node r = rs.item(i);
        NodeList cs = r.getChildNodes();
        System.out.println(rs.getLength());
        for(int j=0;j<cs.getLength();j++){
            System.out.println(cs.getLength());
            Node c = cs.item(j);
            if(c.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                doc.renameNode(c,c.getNamespaceURI(),attlist.get(j));
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void writeXmlFile(Document doc, String filename) {
    try {
        // Prepare the DOM document for writing
        Source source = new DOMSource(doc);

        // Prepare the output file
        File file = new File(filename);
        Result result = new StreamResult(file);

        // Write the DOM document to the file
        Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        xformer.transform(source, result);
    } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
    }
}
}
```

So the `changeTagNames` method is supposed to do the work. I have an ArrayList that holds the 3 Names. But then the indexes of my ArrayList and of my `cs` - NodeList are not the same. I have 3 `<C>` elements but the NodeList `cs` holds seven nodes instead of 3.

How could I solve this? Or is there another, better, more elegant way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/) for this job and write the logic in a [jquery](http://jquery.org)-like style. For example:

```
// Create the list of new tag names
final List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Name1", "Name2", "Name3");
final Document doc = ...

// Find all <R/> elements and iterate over their <C/> children
$(doc).find("R").children("C").each(new Each() {
  public void each(Context context) {

    // Get the appropriate tag name corresponding to the iteration index
    String newTagName = names.get(context.elementIndex() % names.size());

    // Use the DOM API to rename the node
    doc.renameNode(context.element(), "", newTagName);
  }
});

// Check results
System.out.println($(doc));
```

As you can see, this can be done with only a few lines in Java. Another option

```
final Document doc = ...

// Iterate over <R/> elements
for (Match r : $(doc).find("R").each()) {

  // Iterate over <C/> children and rename nodes
  Match c = r.children("C");
  for (int i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {
    doc.renameNode(c.get(i), "", "Name" + (i + 1));
  }
}

// Check results
System.out.println($(doc));
```

Comment: Hello Lukas, thank you. I downloaded "jOOX-1.0.0.zip" and added it as a library. But "import static org.joox.JOOX.*;" leads to the error "The import org.joox cannot be resolved". Could you tell me please what I am doing wrong.

Comment: @Peter: You have to put the library on your compiler/runtime classpath... See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590739/setting-the-classpath) for an example

Answer (score 1):

Seems like XSLT might be a better fit for this.  You could use the `position()` function to generate the element names.  Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673260/150884) for more details.

Comment: Hello Hertzsprung, Thank you. Yes, I agree with you but the requirement is that I can only use java. Regards, Peter